# Android FragmentActivity and SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to embed fragment with MapFragment but unfortunately in setContentView I got RunTimeException  from ZygoteInit.java and I can't get any logs or additional information what I'm doing wrong.
I have my layout which i trying to show:
content_frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:id="@+id/base">

<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and my main activity:
AttachExample.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

public class AttachExample extends FragmentActivity {

private SlidingMenu menu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle(R.string.attach);

    // set the Above View
    try{
      Here goes debuger->      setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
      //and then rise runtime exception
    }   catch(Exception ex){
        ex.getCause(); //But here I can't catch exception 
    }
```

After setContentView flow goes into ZygoteInit.java

```
public void run() {
        try {
            mMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { mArgs });
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) cause;
            }
 here goes debuger->               throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
```

I want to show google map as a fragment in FragmentActivity but I don't know reason why it didn't work.

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slidingmenu.example"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2" >
<!--Permissions-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<permission
        android:name="com.example.hellomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.geoSocial.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
 Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<!--Use-cases-->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/ExampleTheme" >

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDdM48eH3fjqphKmkJYbRL92ZVEnaXWrhI"/>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".AttachExample"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NotificationActivity"/>
</application>
```

In LogCat i found following exception:

```
03-09 17:48:21.955    6858-6858/com.slidingmenu.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:269)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:274)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
        at com.slidingmenu.example.AttachExample.onCreate(AttachExample.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my idea intelliJ I have include google-play-services_lib module

Comment: Post your logcat and manifest.xml file

Comment: it's seems like `google_play_services_lib` not found in your project.

Comment: I added it but idea didn't link it correctly i think, I describe it as next problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288725/android-project-in-intellij-googleplayservices-missing